# How do I get settings in admin/config/people/accounts/fields and admin/config/people/accounts/display into a Feature

Tags: features

How I would get admin/config/people/accounts/fields and admin/config/people/accounts/display into a Feature. I have been looking everywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For account fields, they will be listed under the 'fields' section just like any other. Just look for the fields that start with 'user-'.

For the view modes, I beleive you can export them to features by using the [Dispaly suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module

Comment: Very helpful, it turns out another Feature gobbled them up. I also found that the custom settings to use custom view modes in Display Suite are in the Strongarm variable "field_bundle_settings_...." http://drupal.org/node/1315870#comment-5149928